# Can't edit/delete file shared with Vagrant on Windows 10 (VitualBox issue)

Tags: vagrant, locking, virtualbox, vagrant-windows

Anyone experienced the issue with being unable to delete/edit the file located in Vagrant shared folder?

I'm running latest VirtualBox (5.1.14), Vagrant (1.9.2).
Under Vagrant I'm running v0rtex/xenial64 (ubuntu xenial 16.04)
The issue appears once I bundle React project with gulp (it creates app.xxx.js and app.xxx.js.map files).
When I try to remove the old files, I receive a message of files being busy/locked.
It doesn't matter if I try to remove from Windows 10 machine or from inside Vagrant ubuntu.
The only thing that helps is to shutdown vagrant machine (vagrant halt).
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can run `lsof` to know which process holds your file

```
sudo lsof /vagrant/app.xxx.js.map
```

it will tell you which process is using the file (maybe gulp or other) and it you kill the process you will be able to remove the files

Comment: Thank you, it helped. The process holding the file was nginx.
Strange this is that once I visit the page including that file, nginx was holding a lock on that file due to unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Frederic, I found nginx locking the file for unknown reason.
The issue happened upon visiting the page with the browser (any browser).

The solution was to include "map" extension in static files location in nginx configuration like the following:

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|png|ico|swf|mp3|css|js|woff|ttf|eot|svg|map)$ {
        access_log off;
        expires max;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}
```